# Tone down javascript intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I find the default intellisense suggestions for Javascript irrelevant. Too many native browser functions [I will never use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjPzl.png).

Is there any way to turn off/limit intellisense? e.g. hide browser methods like the one in the link above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the default set of globals, create a `jsconfig.json` file at the root of your project with the content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"]
  }
}
```

This prevents the TypeScript service that VSCode uses for JavaScript IntelliSense from automatically including information about the DOM api.

You can read about [all the avalible `lib` configuration options in the TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).