# Why VS Code showing suggestion even if they are not related to words and apparently also applying them after entering shift + 9?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editor

I am trying to learn gulp and so I am using rename() method but VS Code is showing those unrelated suggestion as shown in the image and as I am typing shift + 9 to make brackets for the method, the first suggestion is getting applied instead of rename() and it is changing to requestAnimationFrame(). Why this behavior is happening and how can I fix this ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2qdt.jpg

Comment: See    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959592/how-to-make-vs-codes-auto-complete-more-strict            but especially https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40965209/tone-down-javascript-intellisense - the jsconfig compiler options really helps reduce those dom recommendatins you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

`(` is treated as commit character for method suggestion. Typing it will accept the current suggestion.

Press escape to cancel out of the current suggestion before pressing `(` or disable commit characters entirely by setting "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false